# Allow flagging of upvoted comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flagging

Currently, Stack Exchange doesn't allow flagging of comments you've upvoted.

For most flag reasons (for example, spam), you shouldn't upvote them in the first place, but it's reasonable for an upvoted comment to be obsolete, which is one of the flag reasons.

I'd rather not use the "Flag question" option, because that may get the wrong comment deleted.

Comment: Just to clarify slightly: it *does* allow flagging of comments other people upvoted, just not comments that *you* upvoted.

Comment: @snailboat I upvoted your comment. Now even if I made the clarification, I wouldn't be able to flag your comment as obsolete. :)

Comment: The equivalent feature request on [Meta.SE]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104184/224428.

Comment: I've run into this a few times now, exactly because of cleaning up obsolete comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed network-wide a few weeks ago.  You can now flag comments you've upvoted, so you should be able to flag my comment above as obsolete now :-)

The Meta Stack Exchange question [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it) appears to now be marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so I'll do the same here.